# Show All Dependency Libraries in External Library under Flutter Plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

I am trying to get an updated list of my plugins to show up on Android Studio in External Libraries under Flutter Plugins. For some reason, newly added plugins (added to pubspec.yaml) do not show up here.

I need it because it enables me to open the plugin library files and see how it is written for easily getting the examples listed in the plugin.

Is there a command I can run on Android Studio terminal or something I can do to refresh the list?

[image: Plugin Image]

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, never did find a solution for this. And these days I'm coding in Kotlin instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [**official documentation**](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) for how to use an upgrade your `pubspec.yaml`:

- **From the terminal**: Run `flutter pub get`.
- **From Android Studio/IntelliJ**: Click Packages get in the action ribbon at the top of `pubspec.yaml`.
- **From VS Code**: Click Get Packages located in right side of the action ribbon at the top of `pubspec.yaml`.

I'd also recommend you to do `flutter clean` from the terminal and run `flutter pub get` to be extra sure everything updated correctly.

Comment: this didn't work. And I had already tried it before but just tried it again. Clean, get, and upgrade does not update my list of plugins. The plugins exist because when I go to the flutter src folder, all my plugins are listed there but it does not show up on Android Studio under External Libraries under Flutter Plugins. I can use the package, I just can't see the plugin.